# cannot run executables after moving /home to new partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu

After moving my /home to a new partition and then reinstalling Ubuntu 10.10, I can't run any files of type x-executable that exist within /home. I just get the "no such file or directory" error. Other kinds of executables, like shell scripts and java executables, are fine.

here's the output of strace on one executable:

```
execve("/home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb", ["/home/evan/android-sdk/platform-"...], [/* 41    vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7c4c7b3000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7c4c7b3000, 4096)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

I posted my original problem [on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165651/eclipse-cannot-find-adb), then someone suggested I take it to serverfault.

Answer (score 1):

The partition may be mounted `noexec`, in which case it will be impossible to execute a script or program directly even if they are marked executable. Remount the partition `exec`.

Comment: it's not `noexec`, however it is `nodev` and `nosuid`. should i get rid of either, or both?

Comment: Not for those files. None of them are setuid, and certainly none of them are device nodes.

Comment: well... any other ideas?

Comment: Try it without nodev. It looks like it's trying to create a device node for debugging.

Comment: Nope, that didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Problem was that the executables were made for 32-bit architecture and i was running amd64. Easily solved, just had to install the ia32-libs package.

Comment: This worked for me, with lib32z1 since ia32-libs isn't around anymore.